# ProgressRing IsActive property is not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

I'm writing a small UWP project also using the MVVM pattern (MVVM Light framework) for my studies and encountered a binding issue in numerous scenarios and controls.

I've taken the effort to isolate one of those into mini example project available [here](https://github.com/Stadzior/TestProgressRing).

The IsActive property of ProgressRing control is not reacting on updates from ViewModel side even through it has:

- INotifyPropertyChanged implemented
- Binding mode explicitly set to TwoWay binding
- UpdateSourceTrigger explicitly set to PropertyChanged

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestProgressRing.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="using:TestProgressRing"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Width="491.282"
    Height="492.308"
    DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=Locator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid
        Width="500"
        Height="800"
        Margin="0,0,-8.667,-307.667"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Width="250"
            Height="50"
            Margin="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Boom">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
        <ProgressRing
            Grid.Row="1"
            Width="500"
            Height="500"
            Margin="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            IsActive="{Binding IsLoading, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestProgressRing
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _isLoading;
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get => _isLoading;
            set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                Set(() => IsLoading, ref _isLoading, value);
            }
        }

        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => 
            IsLoading = !IsLoading);
        }
    }
}
```

Does the UWP controls just simply doesn't works well with regular Binding instead of x:Bind? There are more issues like that for example CalendarPickerView Date property is also don't want to cooperate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay` in your binding. It's always going to be *source* to *target* (i.e. `OneWay`).

The real issue is that you shouldn't be setting `_isLoading = value;` since it's passed in as a `ref` for checking if property value has been changed or not.

So deleting this line will make your code work. You can even simplify it to

```
private bool _isLoading;
public bool IsLoading
{
    get => _isLoading;
    set => Set(ref _isLoading, value);
}
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your binding to:

```
IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}"
```

And your property code to:

```
    private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get {return _isLoading;}
        set
        {
            _isLoading = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(IsLoading));
        }
    }
```

I have used implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` from `Caliburn.Micro` framework, but it can be any other implementation of it that works ;)